# Возможно ли при помощи цикла for создать несколько баз данных?

Tags: база-данных, r, for, rstudio

столкнулся с тем, что нужно загрузить n-ое количество баз данных для последующей обработки в R. Есть ли возможность сделать это при помощи цикла for?

Если делать всё ручками (без цикла) то выглядит это так:

```
    d1 = read.spss("r28iall_32.sav", to.data.frame=TRUE, use.value.labels=FALSE)
    d2 = read.spss("r27iall_32.sav", to.data.frame=TRUE, use.value.labels=FALSE)
    d3 = read.spss("r26iall_32.sav", to.data.frame=TRUE, use.value.labels=FALSE)
    # и т.д.
```

Понимая, что изменяется лишь одна цифра, создаю следующий вектор:

```
c2 = c(9:28)
c2[1]='09'
c3 = c(rep("r",20))
c4 = c(rep("iall_32.sav",20))
g = rev(sort(paste0(c3,c2,c4)))
```

Который принимает значения:

```
 [1] "r28iall_32.sav" "r27iall_32.sav" "r26iall_32.sav" "r25iall_32.sav" "r24iall_32.sav" "r23iall_32.sav" "r22iall_32.sav" "r21iall_32.sav"
 [9] "r20iall_32.sav" "r19iall_32.sav" "r18iall_32.sav" "r17iall_32.sav" "r16iall_32.sav" "r15iall_32.sav" "r14iall_32.sav" "r13iall_32.sav"
[17] "r12iall_32.sav" "r11iall_32.sav" "r10iall_32.sav" "r09iall_32.sav"
```

Создаю цикл:

```
d = NULL
for (i in (1:20)) {
  d = read.spss(g[i], to.data.frame=TRUE, use.value.labels=FALSE)
}
```

и естественно он возвращает только последнюю 20-ю базу. Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом можно каждый раз записывать эти базы в раздел data, чтобы в итоге получить d1,d2,d3 и т.д.?

Comment: А массивов списков нет что ли? Сохраняйте в список а не переменную

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если уж очень нужно, то можно, конечно, создавать переменные динамически, например, с помощью функции `assign()`:

```
> for (i in 1:3) { n <- paste('d', i, sep=''); assign(n, i + 10) }
> d1
[1] 11
> d2
[1] 12
> d3
[1] 13
```

но гораздо логичнее будет использовать список для хранения массива неоднотипных значений (в вашем случае — массива наборов данных):

```
> d <- list()
> for (i in 1:3) { d[[i]] <- as.data.frame(array(1:(i*i),c(i,i))) }
> d
[[1]]
  V1
1  1

[[2]]
  V1 V2
1  1  3
2  2  4

[[3]]
  V1 V2 V3
1  1  4  7
2  2  5  8
3  3  6  9
```

Answer (score 0):

Если Ваши данные однотипны, то можно немного дополнить Ваше решение:

```
df=data.frame()

for (i in (1:20)) {

d = read.spss(g[i], to.data.frame=TRUE, use.value.labels=FALSE)

d$database=g[i] # присваиваем название базы, из которой взяли данные

df=rbind(df,d) # или plyr::rbind.fill(df,d) в случае, если число колонок не совпадает

}
rm(d)
```