# R.Взаимодействие с переменной, имя которой лежит в другой переменной

Tags: r, value

Мне нужно применить функцию к переменной mydata1. Её имя, т.е. "mydata1", я создаю вручную и заношу в переменную datai. Как мне вычленить переменную mydata1 (ее значение), если я знаю, что ее имя "mydata1" лежит именно в переменной datai?
То есть я знаю, что в datai лежит название нужной мне перемененной, но само название этой переменной мне "как бы" неизвестно.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: очень похоже, что вам требуется немного иное. например, что-то в этом духе: [Возможно ли при помощи цикла for создать несколько баз данных?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1195002/178576)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

воспользуйтесь функцией [`get()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/get) из пакета `base`.

пример:

```r
mydata1 <- 42
datai <- 'mydata1'
get(datai)
#> [1] 42
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>